# Winforms, create form instance by form name

Tags: c#, winforms

I need a method that returns a new instance of a form by the name of the form. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public Form GetFormByName(string frmname)
    {
        return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(a => a.BaseType == typeof(Form) && 
            a.Name == frmname).Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

However I get the following error when I attempt to execute this code:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'.**

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx) method which creates an instance of a type given a `Type`:

```
public Form TryGetFormByName(string frmname)
{
    var formType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(a => a.BaseType == typeof(Form) && a.Name == frmname)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (formType == null) // If there is no form with the given frmname
        return null;

    return (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
}
```

Comment: IMO, you should either name it `TryGetFormByName`, or throw an exception if the type is not found. (+1 anyway)

Answer (score 0):

```
Assembly asm = typeof(EnterHereTypeInTheSameAssembly).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType(name);
Form form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```