# WinForms: How to get a reference to a Loaded Form

Tags: winforms, wcf, reflection

I have a Windows Forms Application, that starts a Thread when loading. The thread starts a ServiceHost which exposes a WCF service.

Here the code who start the Thread:

```
Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf (New Ecoute).Ecouter)
    th.Start()
End Sub
```

Here the code who create the service Host

```
Sub Ecouter()
    host = New ServiceHost(GetType(ServiceEmulateur3270))

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IEmulateur3270), New NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost")

    host.Open()
End Sub
```

When I receive a WCF call, in the service's called method, I want to update a control in the main form of my application. How can I get a reference to this Form ?

I found this [Winforms, get form instance by form name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091818/winforms-get-form-instance-by-form-name) but this show how to create a new instance of the form, but I want to get the currently loaded form instead.

OrElse, is it possible for the Thread to pass a reference of the form to the WCF service class ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ParameterizedThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) constructor and pass the Form instance for example, something like this:

```
Dim th As New Thread(AddressOf (New Ecoute).Ecouter)
th.Start(this)

Sub Ecouter(ByVal data As Object)
' you can safely cast data as a Form
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes Simon Mourier, but I don't want to use the form in the "Ecouter" sub. I want to use it in the service's method (operation contract)

Comment: Make what you want clear in the question. Anyway, a Form cannot be easily serialized across service boundaries.