# Open all closed forms in my project one at a time

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I found the following code that will loop through all my closed forms in my project and open a MessageBox and display the form name.

However, how would I modify it so instead of displaying a MessageBox; it would actually open each closed form one by one instead?  I would prefer to use ShowDialog or something like that so each form only opens 1 at a time, and not all at once.  It would be nice that as soon as I close 1 form, then the next form would open, and so on.

```
//http://kellyschronicles.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/show-all-forms-in-a-project-with-c/
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Type[] Types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type myType in Types)
{
   if (myType.BaseType == null) continue;

       if (myType.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.Form")
       {
           //Application.Run(myType.Name());  //This does not work
           MessageBox.Show(myType.Name);
       }   

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
form.ShowDialog();
```

You can use it with default constructor like this or a constructor with arguments but that is a little more tricky.
For more see: [Activator.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

Comment: Error:   Error 5 'System.Activator' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Comment: @fraXis, I know I just fixed that, sorry.

Comment: I changed it to Activator.CreateInstance and that did not error out except the form.ShowDialog() gets this error now: Error 5 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' and no extension method 'ShowDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @fraXis, you have to cast i to `Form` like I did in the updated version.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Type[] Types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type myType in Types)
{
   if (myType.BaseType == null) continue;

       if (myType.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.Form")
       {
           //Application.Run(myType.Name());  //This does not work
           //MessageBox.Show(myType.Name);
           var myForm = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)
                  Activator.CreateInstance(myAssembly.Name, myType.Name);
           myForm.Show();
       }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need provide new instance of the form to your Application.Run method. 
Try to cast it to form and create new instance.
Something like this:

```
public Form TryGetFormByName(string frmname)
{
   var formType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(a => a.BaseType == typeof(Form) && a.Name == frmname).FirstOrDefault();
   if (formType == null) // If there is no form with the given frmname
       return null;
   return (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
}
```

From this post [Winforms, get form instance by form name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091818/winforms-get-form-instance-by-form-name)

Comment: How would I do that with the 'Type myType' ?  How do I convert that to a form instance? Application.Run((Form)myType.Name());  does not work for me.

Comment: Updated to make it clear. Please, also see more details in ink

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if (myType.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.Form")
   {
       //Application.Run((Form)myType);
       Application.Run((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(myType));
   }
```

Comment: Does not work:     Error 5 Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'