# Sub To Summarize Click Events

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows form app where a user clicks a menu item to open a form. Once the menu item is clicked, it checks whether form is open and notifies user if form is open else it opens the form. The code for this is as below

```
Private Sub UsersBarButtonItem_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs) Handles UsersBarButtonItem.ItemClick
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Users).Any Then
        MessageBox.Show("Form Is Open", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        For Each openform In Application.OpenForms()
            If TypeOf (openform) Is Users Then CType(openform, Users).BringToFront()
        Next
    Else
        Dim Form As New Users
        Form.MdiParent = Me
        Form.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like a subroutine to help me avoid repetiting this code for each menu item click events.

Comment: Does the form need to remain open? why not use ShowDialog and not worry about this check

Comment: That is because the forms open in a tab view format inside a mdi container

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how to create an instance of a form thats been passed as a param

Comment: You can use a generic method to make it work for any form class, Public Shared Sub RestoreForm(Of T As Form)().  Call as RestoreForm(Of Users)().

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with a bit of help from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091818/winforms-get-form-instance-by-form-name) thread, you could use reflection/linq to create a new instance of the passed form from its' .Name string If you find a better way, I would be interested to learn myself.

```
        Private Sub ButtonFormB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonFormB.Click

            CheckForm(FormB)

        End Sub

        Private Sub CheckForm(Frm As Form)

            For Each OpnForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
                If OpnForm Is Frm Then
                    OpnForm.BringToFront()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next

            Dim formType =
                Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(Function(a) a.BaseType = GetType(Form) AndAlso a.Name = Frm.Name).FirstOrDefault()

            If formType IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim NewForm As Form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(formType), Form)
                NewForm.Show()
            End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: Had tried that It doesn't work. There's an error 'frm is not defined' The error occurs on the frm in the declaration part

Comment: Yes, im testing it now. Getting same result

Comment: You could just use the default instance of the form and call Frm.Show

Comment: Having to create a Form object, just to call this method is not the correct approach.  The point is to find the one that is already created.

Comment: @Mr. Tripodi That works almost like a form.show() since it opens new form instances outside of the mdiparent

Comment: @HansPassant I thought thats what he was after, once it is open to bring it to front

Comment: @nictert I dont know. Have you considered UserControls?

Comment: @HansPassant Judging from his code in question, he wants to create a new instance if it doesnt exist, and bring it to front if it does

Comment: Sure, that's the easy part.  But if it already existed then he doesn't want another one, the one that's passed as the argument.  Use a generic method or change the argument to Type so it can be called with, say, GetType(Users).

Comment: @Mr Tripodi I might use if I don't find a way out of this

Comment: @HansPassant I dont want to drag this on, but I thought it was passing the default instance of the form, not a new one.

Comment: Still works like a form.show but thanks for the help I deceided to use controls

Comment: No worries. Right when you said what youre doing i figured a UC was a better fit anyway. Also I learned a bit about reflection and default instances. @HansPassant is right (obviously) no need to pass the entire class in.